# File access security for shared directories - Windows Server 2012 R2 - AD

Tags: windows, security

Our application uses a shared directory to store files that are 'checked out', modified via our application, and then 'checked in' to a shared directory, which is being accessed via SMB (The environment is hosted on a set of AWS servers, and our end-users access it via Citrix).

All users have read, write, etc. permissions for the shared directory.

We've recently changed the architecture of the application a bit. Previously, each user had his/her own subdirectory in the shared directory where the checked in/checked out file was stored.

In the new architecture, the individual subdirectories aren't used, so that all files checked in by users are stored directly into the shared directory. Users are then allowed to checkout/checkin any file in the shared directory.

The checkout process involves doing a File.Copy of the library version of the file to the user's local, non-shared directory. The user then uses our application to make changes to the file, which is then saved locally and File.Copy'd back into the shared directory.

Except that in the new architecture, the 'checkout' operation fails when User 2 attempts to checkout a file that was originally checked in by User1. As near as we can tell, this is because when, for example, User 1 checks a file in to the shared directory, the file implicitly receives a security entry for his specific AD login.  A subsequent File.Copy operation by User 2 gets a permission error.  If a full admin for the host system removes the security entry for User 1, then the File.Copy from the shared directory to User 2's local directory works fine.

Note that both users are assigned to a group with read, write, modify, etc to the shared directory (but not 'full control').

This doesn't *seem* like that unusual of a situation. We haven't (yet) tried to see if the application can programmatically remove the security entry created on the checkin - even assuming that's possible, it would be nice not to have to resort to that. But we've not found any arrangement of security settings that works.

Any information or suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks...

---

As requested:

```
\\citrixfile01\Shares\clients\002\library 
ALIGHTENT\002.EightTwoConversion:(I)(OI)(CI)(M) 
NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX) 
S-1-5-21-3973462947-2300097736-545649627-500:(I)(OI)(CI)(F) 
ALIGHTENT\citrix:(I)(OI)(CI)(F) 
ALIGHTENT\alightcalc:(I)(OI)(CI)(M) 
ALIGHTENT\Domain Admins:(I)(OI)(CI)(F) 
BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)

\\citrixfile01\Shares\clients\002\library\AML_AmPac_8.2.amox 
ALIGHTENT\002.Admin1:(I)(M) 
ALIGHTENT\citrix:(I)(F) 
ALIGHTENT\AEAdmin2:(I)(M) 
ALIGHTENT\Domain Admins:(I)(F) 
BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
```

Comment: I don't know whether `File.Copy` copies permissions or not; probably not, in which case the permissions being assigned to the files are determined by the permissions on the shared directory.  Please post the details of the shared directory's permissions.

Comment: Hello Harry -Thanks for the quick reply...  the shared directory security list has an entry ("002.EightTwoConversion") for the AD group to which both admins belong.  The permissions for that entry are Modify, Read & execute, List folder contents, Read and Write.

Comment: Is that permission inheritable?  What does `002.EightTwoConversion` mean - that doesn't look like Windows terminology, is the directory in question located on a non-Windows server?  What permissions are set on the file that was created by User 1?

Comment: The permissions for "002.EightTwoConversion" are inheritable. The name itself is just an internal convention format we use. The shared directory is on a Windows server, but our application is running on a different Windows server in the AWS environment. The created file gets the permissions of the directory, but *without* the "002.EightTwoConversion" entry, but *with* an entry for User 1.

Comment: As mentoned in my initial message, if we delete the security entry for User 1 on the created file, then User2 is able to copy it from the shared directory. The behavior we observed suggested that when User1 wrote the file, he became the sole 'owner' of the file such that User2 couldn't access it for doing the File.Copy.  [thanks for your continued assistance!]

Comment: Removing the entry for User 1 and making no other changes *can't* change the level of access for User 2 - the nature of the algorithm used to check access rights makes that impossible - so something else must be happening, possibly as a side-effect of making that change.  I really need to see the exact permissions on the parent, on a file as created by User 1, and on the same file after the security entry is deleted.  Use the `icacls` command and copy-and-paste the output into your question, or email me screenshots of the "Advanced Security Settings" dialog.

Comment: Hello Harry- Thanks for sticking with this for us.  After this comment I'll add what we got from icacls...

Comment: Shared directory output: \\citrixfile01\Shares\clients\002\library ALIGHTENT\002.EightTwoConversion:(I)(OI)(CI)(M)
                          NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
                          S-1-5-21-3973462947-2300097736-545649627-500:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                          ALIGHTENT\citrix:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                          ALIGHTENT\alightcalc:(I)(OI)(CI)(M)
                          ALIGHTENT\Domain Admins:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                          BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)

Comment: The file that won't copy: \\citrixfile01\Shares\clients\002\library\AML_AmPac_8.2.amox ALIGHTENT\002.Admin1:(I)(M)
                                                             ALIGHTENT\citrix:(I)(F)
                                                             ALIGHTENT\AEAdmin2:(I)(M)
                                                             ALIGHTENT\Domain Admins:(I)(F)
                                                             BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)

Comment: For future reference, it is preferable to edit that sort of information into your question rather than posting it in the comments.  I've copied it into the question on your behalf.

Comment: OK, the "inherited" ACL doesn't match up with the parent ACL at all.  That could be caused if the ACL is being copied along with the file, depending on how the copy is implemented, but it seems unlikely that .NET's File.Copy would do that.  Any chance the file is being copied to a different location on the same server and then *moved* to the `library` folder?  That is the most common way to wind up with a mismatched ACL.

Comment: Yay! You were correct - we were using 'File.Move' - not sure we would ever have figured that out. Changed it to 'File.Copy' and the problem is fixed.  Thanks so much for your patience and your help...

Answer (score 0):

When a file is moved, Windows does not update the ACL to add or remove inherited permissions.  This is presumably for backwards-compatibility reasons; the permissions model looked somewhat different in the earliest versions of Windows NT.

Your options are to copy the file instead of moving it, or to explicitly reset the permissions after the file has been moved.

If you want to explicitly reset the permissions, you can do this using `File.SetAccessControl`.  To apply the inherited permissions for the new location, the `FileSecurity` object should contain an empty ACL and the `AreAccessRulesProtected` property should be false.